SQL IF parameter value does not equal field value UPDATE SET field value to parameter value
I'm creating a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio where I'm searching the table for a specific row depending upon a user's MS ID. The request is being sent from a form within a web app where a user has updated their information and the stored procedure searches for the record to perform the update.
Here's what I've got:
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [MY_USER_TABLE] WHERE MSID = @MSID
    UPDATE [ANA].[MY_USER_TABLE]
    SET FName = @FName, LName = @LName, EmpID = @EmpID, Email = @Email, PrimPlat = @PrimPlat, OtherPlat1 = @OtherPlat1, OtherPlat2 = @OtherPlat2
    WHERE MSID = @MSID
END

The issue I'm having is I'm getting an error saying "Invalid column name" in the IF statements:
IF (@FName != FName)

But, the column name seems fine when I set it to the parameter:
SET FName = @FName

Is there a reason why my query doesn't recognize the column name when comparing it to the parameter? Is there a better way to compare parameter values to column field values to see if they differ and need to be updated?
UPDATE: I've modified the code so that it works regardless if there's an update.

Just update every column?  If it's already the same, then overwiting it won't change it. Changing one row multiple times (once per column changed) is going to be much slower than changing all the columns once.

As for the syntax, you need a BEGIN after each IF... IF...BEGIN...END (The END matches the BEGIN, not the IF). And the IF statement doesn't read from the SELECT statement. You'd need SELECT @X=X, @Y=Y FROM foo WHERE bar then check the variables against the parameters.

@MatBailie If the user's last name changes due to marriage, or if they have a change of address, wouldn't it be easier to change only the field that is different from the parameter?

@MatBailie Are you saying my IF should look like this: IF (@FName != SELECT FName FROM [MY_USER_TABLE] WHERE MSID = @MSID)

MS SQL Server error system is very correct. In IF (@FName != FName) variable Fname is not defined. Also, as said in comments, multiple updates are worse than a single update. The system runs a separate transaction for each  update. You can do something like this.
update my_user_table set
FName = isnull(nullif(FName, @FName),FName),
LName = isnull(nullif(LName, @LName),LName),
MSID = isnull(nullif(MSID, @MSID),MSID)
where MSID = @MSID

Or even simpler
update my_user_table set
FName = @FName,
LName = @LName
where MSID = @MSID


Sorry. Just saw this after I made my update. I'll give you the credit for it.
